# How to upload file in angular 2 with meteor

Tags: meteor, angular, file-upload, angular-meteor

How to upload file in angular 2 with meteor . please help me ! . thanks for watching

Comment: Please show some effort on your side, StackOverflow is for specific programming problems only. You should paste some code or error that you have a problem with.

Comment: Is this chapter not answering your question? https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/handling-files-with-collectionfs

Comment: Great . thanks for help me !

Answer (score 1):

Urigo,
Related to the article, where is image stored. I mean static path image when we upload file.